# Ubuntu server does not seem to detect external drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, storage

So i have recently installed Ubuntu server on a machine. Which has all gone great the box is up and running and working as expected. 
The issue i face is that i have A 4tb external HDD that i wish to use with the ubuntu box.

I am new to Linux and have tried my best to figure this out, but i am really quite stuck. 
Hoping to catch some help from an experienced Linux user.

I have the following outputs that i have generated which may be of assistance.

Installed webmin and viewed drives.
this shows the following output

```
SATA device A 1.86 TiB ATA TOSHIBA MQ03ABB22 IDE parameters Identify drive
SCSI device B 3.72 TiB Seagate Expansion Desk0 Identify drive
```

The drive works perfectly when i connect it to a Windows machine.

I have used diskpart in windows to completely clean the drive.

reconnected to Linux box. I am now seeing the following output.

```
    curtis@plex:~$ sudo fdisk -l
    Disk /dev/loop0: 89.1 MiB, 93417472 bytes, 182456 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

    Disk /dev/loop1: 93.8 MiB, 98336768 bytes, 192064 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

    Disk /dev/loop2: 64.1 MiB, 67239936 bytes, 131328 sectors    
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

    Disk /dev/loop3: 55 MiB, 57614336 bytes, 112528 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

    Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
    Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
    Disklabel type: gpt
    Disk identifier: DEF5BDE2-8B0C-46EE-A896-68CF8C794AD1
    Device Start End Sectors Size Type
    /dev/sda1 2048 1050623 1048576 512M EFI System
    /dev/sda2 1050624 3907026943 3905976320 1.8T Linux filesystem
    curtis@plex:~$ lsusb
    Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bc2:331a Seagate RSS LLC
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
    curtis@plex:~$ lsblk
    NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    loop0 7:0 0 89.1M 1 loop /snap/core/8268
    loop1 7:1 0 93.8M 1 loop /snap/core/8935
    loop2 7:2 0 64.1M 1 loop /snap/powershell/104
    loop3 7:3 0 55M 1 loop /snap/core18/1705
    sda 8:0 0 1.8T 0 disk
    ├─sda1 8:1 0 512M 0 part /boot/efi
    └─sda2 8:2 0 1.8T 0 part /
    sdb 8:16 0 3.7T 0 disk
    curtis@plex:~$

any help would be greatly appreciated. 
The external drive is the 4TB disk. 
Please let me know if you require any further information.
```

Comment: Add the messages generated in `/var/log/messages` at the moment you connect the drive ?

Comment: Hi, the path does not exist. I am able to get to /var/log. located in here are is only the following 
curtis@plex:~$ ls /var/log
alternatives.log       cloud-init.log  journal    syslog
apt                    dist-upgrade    kern.log   syslog.1
auth.log               dpkg.log        landscape  tallylog
bootstrap.log          faillog         lastlog    unattended-upgrades
btmp                   fontconfig.log  lxd        wtmp
cloud-init-output.log  installer       samba

Comment: Thanks for that, i have the output, what would be the best way for me to share this? It exceeds the maximum length for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If I read you lsblk-output correctly /dev/sdb does not have any partitions. You should pick a partitioning tool of your choice and create at least one with a file system. Since I don't know your preferences for the external drive, e.g. if you want to use them with Windows and Linux, I can't recommend the perfect choice.

Using with Windows and Linux: format on Windows with NTFS or FAT32.
Using Linux only: format it as ext4, for example with gparted (GUI), fdisk or parted (command line), after partitioning use mkfs.ext4 on the partition to init the file system.

Then preferrably use `udisksctl` (command line) to mount and unmount the drive as non-root user when needed. (I assume your server has no monitor/ UI/ X-Server, thus no gvfs/ desktop-based mount/ unmount with simple clicking.)

You could also set up user mount through /etc/fstab, but your intention is not clear to me.

Comment: so i have tried to partition and format the disk using parted, however when executing $ sudo parted the console seems to hang and not do anything. 

I have reconnected the drive to Windows and can verify that i can format/partition the drive to NTFS using diskpart, however then when connecting it back to the Linux box the same occurs.

Comment: Sounds interesting and is maybe hardware/ kernel related. On the server run `sudo dmesg --clear` once, to clear all kernel log messages. Then plug in the drive, wait 1-2s and run `dmesg` (without --clear) to display kernel messages. Maybe there are some error codes pointing to negotiation errors (usb <-> Kernel) or hardware issues (device <-> Kernel).

Comment: Hi, This is the information from dmesg
I have excluded some of the data as it would make this too long. 
[258626.943660] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 7814037167 512-byte logical blocks: (4.00 TB/3.64 TiB)
[258626.943668] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[258626.943844] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[258626.943851] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
[258626.944189] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[258626.944484] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)